# A question about cond expressions in Scheme

Tags: conditional-statements, scheme, language-lawyer, racket, chez-scheme

With Chez Scheme version 9.5.5, consider the two examples of `cond`:

```lisp
(cond #t (else 2))
(cond (> 2 1) (else 2))
```

The first expression evaluates to `#t`, while the second expression evaluates to `1`.

It seems that the first expression is first expanded to `(cond (#t #t) (else 2))`, while the second expression is expanded to `(cond ((> 2 1) 1) (else 2))` before evaluation.

My question is: Since the value of expression `(> 2 1)` is `#t`, It is counter-intuitive to me that the two `cond` expressions have different values. Are there good reasons to define `cond` in such a way?

Edit: I tried the two expressions with GNU Guile 3.0.1:

- The expression `(cond #t (else 2))` triggers an erorr, which says "cond: invalid clause in subform #t of (cond #t (else 2)".
- The expression `(cond (> 2 1) (else 2))` evaluates to `1` as with Chez Scheme 9.5.5.
- The expression `(cond (#t) (else 2))` evaluates to `#t`.

Edit2: With CHICKEN Scheme 5.1.0:

- The expression `(cond #t (else 2))` triggers an erorr, which says "during expansion of (cond ...) - in `cond' - not a proper list: #t".
- The expression `(cond (> 2 1) (else 2))` evaluates to `1` as with Chez Scheme and GNU Guile.
- The expression `(cond (#t) (else 2))` evaluates to `#t` but with a warning which says "Warning: clause following `#t' clause in` cond': (else 2)".

Comment: I suggest reading the [specification for `cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html), rather than trying to guess how it behaves.

Comment: @amalloy The question is not about how it behaves, but about why it behaves in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression raises an exception in Chez 9.5.4, which is the most recent *release*:

```
> (cond #t (else 2))

Exception: invalid syntax (cond #t (else 2))
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

I'm not sure why 9.5.5 would be different in that regard; if true, this probably points to a change in the underlying implementation of `cond` in 9.5.5.

In any case, [the `cond` form](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5) takes one or more *`<cond clause>`* arguments, and an optional `else` clause, where a *`<cond clause>`* must be of the form *`(<test> <expression1> ...)`*; i.e., a *`<cond clause>`* must be a parenthesized expression containing one test form and zero or more expressions. Each *`<cond clause>`* is evaluated in order until a *`<test>`* evaluates to true, after which the subsequent expressions are evaluated in order, and the value of the final expression is returned. When there are no subsequent expressions in a true *`<cond clause>`*, the value of *`<test>`* is returned.

The expression `(cond #t (else 2))` violates this (because the first *`<cond clause>`* is malformed) and should probably raise a syntax error, which 9.5.4 does. If 9.5.5 does not raise a syntax error in this case, a bug report should probably be filed with the maintainers. Note again that 9.5.5 is not a released version of Chez Scheme, though.

This was already stated above, but I'll repeat here: when a *`<test>`* expression evaluates to true, and there are no subsequent expressions in the *`<cond clause>`*, the clause evaluates to the value of *`<test>`*. So this is expected to work according to R6RS, and it works as expected in 9.5.4:

```
> (cond (#t) (else 2))
#t
```

This would also be the correct way to express the second expression in the OP question. Here I have modified the `else` clause to return `3` to make it a bit more clear which branch is evaluated:

```
> (cond ((> 2 1)) (else 3))
#t
> (cond ((> 1 2)) (else 3))
3
```

To be clear: the first *`<cond clause>`* in the first expression above is `((> 2 1))`, which contains the *`<test>`* `(> 2 1)`. This test evaluates to `#t`, and since there are no subsequent expressions in this clause, the clause returns `#t`. The second expression has `((> 1 2))` as its *`<cond clause>`*, with the *`<test>`* `(> 1 2)`. This test evaluates to `#f`, so evaluation proceeds to the next *`<cond clause>`*, `(else 3)`, which returns `3`.

The unaltered second expression posted in the question behaves the same way in 9.5.4 as reported by OP for 9.5.5. This behavior is exactly as R6RS specifies it should be:

```
> (cond (> 2 1) (else 2))
1
```

The first *`<cond clause>`* here is the form `(> 2 1)`, where `>` is the *`<test>`*, and `2` and `1` are *`<expression1>`* and *`<expression2>`*. Now, if *`<test>`* evaluates to true, then the subsequent expressions are evaluated, and the value of the final expression is returned.

So, with `(cond (> 2 1) (else 2))`, the first *`<cond clause>`* is `(> 2 1)`, with the *`<test>`* being the expression `>`, which evaluates to a procedure, which is not `#f` and thus a true value. Then the subsequent expressions `2` and `1` are evaluated in turn, and the value of the final expression is `1`, which is then returned.

Note that the form `(> 2 1)` is not evaluated as a *`<test>`* here; the form `>` alone is evaluated as a *`<test>`*. Further, `(< 2 1)` should behave identically to `(> 2 1)` in this case. In fact, any similar form will behave identically to this, so long as the first element does not evaluate to `#f`:

```
> (cond (> 2 1) (else 3))
1
> (cond (< 2 1) (else 3))
1
> (cond ('any-truthy-thing 2 1) (else 3))
1
```

### Version Update

A few days after I posted this answer the new version of Chez was released. Note that OP was working with 9.5.5, which was never a release version (presumably OP built 9.5.5 from source). The new release is 9.5.6. I did not build 9.5.5 from source to test any of this; I used the current release at the time, which was 9.5.4. I have now updated to 9.5.6 on my main machine, and both 9.5.4 and 9.5.6 have identical behavior for the expressions OP asked about. The first OP expression was `(cond #t (else 2))`, which OP found to evaluate to `#t`. Chez should *not* return `#t` in this case, but is required to raise a syntax error, as explained in my answer above. An issue was raised with the maintainers for 9.5.5, but the problem could not be reproduced. The second expression was `(cond (> 2 1) (else 2))`; this expression was treated correctly by 9.5.4, OP's 9.5.5, and now also by the current 9.5.6 release.

Comment: Thanks for explain in detail why both  `(cond (> 2 1) (else 3))` and `(cond (< 2 1) (else 3))`returns 1. Isn't this behavior a little bit confusing?  A little bit referential transparency could make the language more consistent.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li -- I'm not sure how referential transparency is related, and Scheme seems pretty consistent to me. I don't find this confusing; of course you have to know how `cond` works to use it, but the rules are simple. What can throw people who come from other languages is that parentheses carry meaning in lisps, i.e., you can't group things with them any old way, or add them, or take them away on a whim. `((> 2 1))` is different from `(> 2 1)`.

Comment: Seeing `>` in `(> 2 1)` might be confusing here, since this _looks_ like a comparison, but it is not a comparison in this case. You can just as well do `(cond ('anything 1 2) (else 42))` --> `2`. The behavior is strictly a consequence of the way that `cond` is defined. But it is rare that you would write any `cond` form this way; you should only take advantage of the test-only clause when it makes your code more clear.

Comment: I mean if one replace (> 2 1) with its value, which is #t, the value of the enclosing expression should not change. F(True: Bool) should be equivalent with F(2>1).

Comment: @JohnZ.Li -- The value of the expression `(> 2 1)` is `#t` under normal evaluation rules, but that is not the case here. Under normal evaluation rules a parenthesized expression, e.g., `(> 2 1)`, is a function call where `>` is a function with arguments `2` and `1`, _unless the first element is a syntactic keyword in which case it is a macro call._ `>` is a function, but `cond` is a syntactic keyword. Functions evaluate their arguments, but macros evaluate their arguments in a manner determined by the definition of the macro....

Comment: Since `cond` is a syntactic keyword, a `cond` form _does not evaluate its arguments under normal evaluation rules._ Instead, `cond` evaluates its arguments in the manner specified in the RnRS standards. One consequence of this is that the form `(> 2 1)`, when in the position of a _`<cond clause>`_, is not evaluated as a function call, but by the rules described in my answer. IOW, the value of `(> 2 1)` is _not_ `#t` when it is a _`<cond clause>`_. The value of `(> 2 1)` in this case is `1`, and replacing `(> 2 1)` with `1` does _not_ change the value of the enclosing expression.

Comment: The root issue here is that expressions _only have meaning in the presence of an evaluation model_. For _any_ language, understanding the evaluation model is key to understanding the language.

Answer (score -1):

As always, [read the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html):

> ```
> [test-expr]
> ```
>
> The result of the *test-expr* is returned as the result of the **cond** form. The test-expr is not in tail position.

So the first expression returns `#t`, as expected.

The second expression also returns `#t`, I am uncertain as to why you say you are getting `1`.

If you want to return something specific you should properly form it:

```
(cond [#t "hey it's true"])

--> "hey it's true"
```

However, Chez uses a few C-isms, and I believe that the integer-as-boolean is one of them. It does not surprise me that Chez returned `1` for `#t`. (Disclaimer: I have not used Chez personally.)

Comment: The second expression returns 1 with Chez scheme 9.5.5. Are you saying that Chez Scheme 9.5.5 has a bug concerning "cond"?

Comment: No, I just read Chez’s docs (yes, I know I linked _**Racket’s**_ docs). Let me update the answer with something I left out because I couldn’t remember if I was correct about it...

Comment: While values that are not `#f` are true values in Scheme, the comparison operators must only return `#t` or `#f`, per the standards; `>` will _never_ return a numeric result. Also, your `(cond [#t "hey it's true"])` doesn't really match with anything OP code is trying to express.

Comment: First, I know the docs — I linked them, even. Without downloading and running a copy of Chez myself, I have only the OP’s word that he is getting a `1` from the expression; further, various scheme interpreters are notorious for having some behaviors that don’t exactly follow the standard. Second, OP is doing something weird instead of using the 2-element list form that each `cond` clause is expected to take for general usefulness, so, my example stands as a perfectly correct example of use with the same degree of made-up-ness that OP’s original made up examples express, but more demonstrative.

Comment: Well, you linked the Racket docs, but Racket is not Scheme. Your statement "_it does not surprise me that Chez returned 1 for #t_" indicates that you may have missed that part of the R6RS spec, because this can't happen in a comparison with `>`, and this is not why OP's second expression (which is perfectly legal) behaves as it does; I explained this behavior in my answer. OP's first example contains a syntax violation. Your example is a syntactically correct form which does not demonstrate anything about either of OP's example expressions.